# Skobbler and OpenSeaMaps

Tags: skmaps

I'd like to know if somehow Skobbler might natively support OpenSeaMaps? If not do you have some advice how to display all the data efficient, because the plan *B* is to get all the data from OpenSeaMaps and display/draw them manually (like parsing JSON data, etc.). Maybe you're planning to add such functionality in the future or it is possible to prepare some customized sea data (map features from openseamaps).

Thanks.

Bart S.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there are no specific developments regarding OpenSeaMap - the current version focuses on land features & navigation (cars, bikes, pedestrians).

This is also true for the map format (the map format used by skobbler/Telenav) - the schema of the map is optimized for land features not water/sea features, so currently no OpenSeaMap features are imported.